# function doesn't change the variable as its supposed to

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want the `reset` function to change the `turn` value to `"X"` but it doesnt and after every game it changes the starting turn so game 1 x would start, game 2 o starts, game 3 x...,anyway i put a `turn = "X"` at the first line of the `reset` function but it doesnt do anything

```js
let board = new Array(9).fill();
const squares = document.getElementsByClassName("square");
let turn = "X";
let X = 0;
let O = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
  let element = squares[i];
  element.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (!element.textContent) {
      element.textContent = turn;
      console.log(e.target.id);
      board[e.target.id] = e.target.textContent;
      console.log(board);
      findWinningCombination();
      checkDraw();
      turn = turn === "X" ? "O" : "X";
    }
  });
}

function findWinningCombination() {
  const winningCombinations = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];

  for (const combination of winningCombinations) {
    const [a, b, c] = combination;

    if (
      board[a] === board[b] &&
      board[a] === board[c] &&
      board[(a, b, c)] != undefined
    ) {
      switch (turn) {
        case "X":
          X++;
          xText.textContent = `X: ${X}`;
          break;
        
        case "O":
          O++;
          oText.textContent = `O: ${O}`;
          break;
      }
      reset()
    }
  }
}

function checkDraw() {
  if (!(findWinningCombination() || board.includes(undefined))) {
    //if there is a win or any empty squares it returns false if the board is full and there is no win it returns true
    reset();
  }
}

function reset() {
  turn = "X";
  board = new Array(9).fill();
  for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    squares[i].textContent = "";
  }
}
```

```css
#board {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
  gap: 1vmin;
}

.square {
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  background-color: #252525;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 10vw;
  min-height: 10vw;
  font-size: 10vw;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>TicTacToe</title>
</head>
<body>

<p id="xText">X: 0</p>
<p id="oText">O: 0</p>

<div id="board">
    <div id="0" class="square"></div>
    <div id="1" class="square"></div>
    <div id="2" class="square"></div>
    <div id="3" class="square"></div>
    <div id="4" class="square"></div>
    <div id="5" class="square"></div>
    <div id="6" class="square"></div>
    <div id="7" class="square"></div>
    <div id="8" class="square"></div>
</div>

<button class="button-6" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What specific observation are you making which indicates that `turn = "X";` doesn't set `turn` to `"X"`?

Comment: because x doesn't start at the next game

Comment: Every time I press the "reset" button in the code snippet above, X starts the next game.

Comment: dont use the reset play a game and win with x

Comment: i solved it thank you for enlighting me with the comment i relised what i done wron

Comment: It doesn't change anything when someone wins the game, because you execute the "turn flip" afterwards.

Comment: i posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well in your code you call the `reset` function in the `findWinningCombination` function or the `checkDraw` function and after that you use the question mark condition that changes the `turn` to X if its O or O if its X so the `reset` would be called before the turn change i just moved the  `turn = turn === "X" ? "O" : "X";` up 2 lines above the function calls and it works

Answer (score 0):

You can change turn X According to you when reset game or cleanbord..

```js
let board = new Array(9).fill();
const squares = document.getElementsByClassName("square");
let turn = "X";
let X = 0;
let O = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
  let element = squares[i];
  element.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (!element.textContent) {
      element.textContent = turn;
      console.log(e.target.id);
      board[e.target.id] = e.target.textContent;
      console.log(board);
      findWinningCombination();
      checkDraw();
      turn = turn === "X" ? "O" : "X";
    }
  });
}

function findWinningCombination() {
  const winningCombinations = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];

  for (const combination of winningCombinations) {
    const [a, b, c] = combination;

    if (
      board[a] === board[b] &&
      board[a] === board[c] &&
      board[(a, b, c)] != undefined
    ) {
      switch (turn) {
        case "X":
          X++;
          xText.textContent = `X: ${X}`;
          break;
        
        case "O":
          O++;
          oText.textContent = `O: ${O}`;
          break;
      }
      cleanBord()
    }
  }
}

function checkDraw() {
  if (!(findWinningCombination() || board.includes(undefined))) {
    //if there is a win or any empty squares it returns false if the board is full and there is no win it returns true
    reset();
  }
}
function cleanBord(){ 
  //turn = "X"; 
  board = new Array(9).fill();
  for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    squares[i].textContent = "";
  }
}
function reset() {  
  turn = "X";
  X = 0;
  O = 0;  
  document.getElementById('xText').innerText = `X: ${X}`
  document.getElementById('oText').innerText = `O: ${0}`
  cleanBord();
}
```

```css
#board {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
  gap: 1vmin;
}

.square {
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  background-color: #252525;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 10vw;
  min-height: 10vw;
  font-size: 10vw;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>TicTacToe</title>
</head>
<body>

<p id="xText">X: 0</p>
<p id="oText">O: 0</p>

<div id="board">
    <div id="0" class="square"></div>
    <div id="1" class="square"></div>
    <div id="2" class="square"></div>
    <div id="3" class="square"></div>
    <div id="4" class="square"></div>
    <div id="5" class="square"></div>
    <div id="6" class="square"></div>
    <div id="7" class="square"></div>
    <div id="8" class="square"></div>
</div>

<button class="button-6" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code only answers (even if the code is great) are not considered good answers on Stack Overflow. You should add explanation as to what your codes does and how it solves the problem.

Comment: What you've added for an "explanation" isn't really an explanation. Consider adding descriptive comments in the code and explain what the original problem was and how/why your code solves it.